# Conversion from 'double' to 'decimal' and 'string' to 'double' error in VB list

Tags: vb.net, list, oop, error-handling, type-conversion

So I have created this list called 'menu' in which I have stored menu items' names and prices. I have done this using a class 'MenuItem' where I have declared `name` as `string` and `price` as `decimal`. But I'm getting this error in the list that It can't be converted from 'double' to 'decimal' and 'string' to 'double'. I do have the option strict on, but even with it off I get this error when I run the code.

I have tried using the cdbl() function like so: `.cost =cdbl(2.0 * txtburger.text)` but it still doesn't work.

```
 Dim menu As New List(Of MenuItem) From
     {
         New MenuItem With {.Name = "Burger", .Cost = 2.0 * txtburger.Text},
         New MenuItem With {.Name = "wrap", .Cost = 2.0 * txtwrap.Text},
         New MenuItem With {.Name = "Parmesan", .Cost = 2.5 * txtparmesan.Text},
         New MenuItem With {.Name = "Stirfry", .Cost = 3.0 * txtstirfry.Text},
```

Comment: Assuming with `price` you mean `Cost`, if this property is of Type Decimal, this: `2.0` is a Double value and this: `txtburger.Text` is a String. This: `Option Strict ON` is what you should set in in the Project's Properties. It will help a lot.

Comment: I did state in the post, that my Option strict is already On. And it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: If you have Option Strict set to `ON`, then you cannot run the app, because it doesn't let you compile it, since you're trying to set a Decimal property value multiplying a Double by a String. Also, the whole thing you have posted here would be squiggling red all over. `D` is the Decimal literal type character (so, this is Double: `2.0`, this is Decimal: `2.0D`) and `Decimal.TryParse()` can turn the content of a string into a Decimal value, if it validates. -- Option Strict `ON` helps you because it lets you see it immediately when you make mistakes like these, so you can fix them right away.

Comment: I asked this before. Do you have your own MenuItem class? The MenuItem class provided by the .net framework does not have a Cost property.

Comment: Just use ```.Cost = 2.0 * Convert.ToDecimical(txtWhatever.Text.Replace(".",","))``` *as also mentioned by @Caius Jard in his answer below.*

Answer (score -1):

> `.cost =cdbl(2.0 * txtburger.text)`

`2.0` is a number

`txtburger.Text` is a string

A string and a number cannot be multiplied together. CDbl isn't involved yet; VB is trying to do your `number * string` operation before passing the result to CDbl

Convert only the text part to double so you end up performing `number * number`. Take a look at the [Convert.ToDouble](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble?view=net-5.0) and [Convert.ToDecimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=net-5.0) methods

If you're still struggling with this, throw away all your textboxes and replace them with nunericupdown controls, so you can use their Value property (which is a number) rather than a textbox's Text (which is a string)

Comment: for some reason I only get this string to double error when my event handler is dealing with a check box. When I change it to a 'button' and then run the program and click the button, it doesn't give this error. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "nunericupdown control"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=net-5.0